# Fourier series of periodic parabola function

Tags: fourier-series

I am trying to find Exponential Fourier series coefficients for a periodic parabolic function

$$ f(t) = t^2, \quad -\pi \le t \le \pi $$

using derivative property of Fourier series. As otherwise, it's a bit tedious to go and compute FS coefficients by integrating them through formula we have for Fourier series coefficients.

The results I am getting is incorrect (I am differentiating parabolic function thrice to get two impulse trains, FS coefficients for impulse trains are $1/T$ and then applying derivative rule), FS coefficients that we must be getting should be purely real and even but I am getting them as purely imaginary. Can someone please correct me where I am wrong.

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: It's hard to tell you where you are going wrong unless you edit your question to show us your calculations. Please see the [MathJax basic tutorial and reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/856) if you need help on how to enter maths on this site.

Comment: I totally understand but unfortunately I am not allowed to upload picture of my approach here as getting error that I must be having atleast 10 reputation to post images :( .